# Valor recibido de un input no se almacena en la base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql

Una ayuda tengo un campo de mi formulario y lo e puesto disabled y al momento de insertar el valor del campo que esta por defecto me guarda en la base de datos pero me guarda vacio no se guarda el contenido del campo como lo podria solucionar soy nuevo en esto

Comment: Consejo:redacta títulos objetivos y que describan el problema que enfrentas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un elemento `readonly` no es editable, pero si se envía el valor del campo en el formulario correspondiente. Un elemento `disabled` no es editable y no se envía el valor del campo al enviar el formulario.

Por lo que si quieres que tu input no se modifique pero si que se envie a la base de datos, debes utilizar `readonly` y no `disabled`

Comment: Okey muchas gracias me sirvio de maravilla me funciono ya no sabia que hacer esta leyendo libros y no encontraba respuesta la experiencia que tienen usted es increible muchas gracias